# Does Linux Filesystem(ext4) synchronise writes to different files in the same disk?

Tags: filesystems

I am working on an application in Linux that includes Append Only writes to a file from multiple threads. Currently, i am taking a mutex lock from each thread and then appending to a file. I want to optimise on performance of my application and was thinking of creating multiple files(lets call segments) and then each thread can just write to its own segment.
This file is like a Write Ahead Log and used only during application boot.

I was wondering if above looks like a good strategy to optimise on IO.
Is there any overhead of creating multiple files for writes on the same local disk?

Comment: That's actually a complicated question – see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154446/is-file-append-atomic-in-unix/) questions different answers over at stackoverflow. Generally, it's definitely not guaranteed for writes of any size. For small writes, this might be guaranteed (not quite sure what it is, really). This sounds like a logging problem, is that right?

Comment: oh wait, this is one process, multiple threads, so!

Comment: Yeah its one process and multiple threads writing to one/multiple files.
IIRC, in Linux(and most POSIX), write is an atomic system call, right?

Answer (score 2):

from `man 2 write`:

> According to POSIX.1-2008/SUSv4 Section XSI 2.9.7 ("Thread Interactions with Regular File Operations"):
>
> > All  of the following functions shall be atomic with respect to each other in the effects specified in POSIX.1-2008 when
> > they operate on regular files or symbolic links: ...
>
> Among the APIs subsequently listed are write() and writev(2).  And among the effects that should be atomic across threads (and
> processes) are  updates of the file offset.  However, on Linux before version 3.14, this was not the case: if two processes that share an open file description (see open(2)) perform a write() (or writev(2)) at the same time, then the I/O operations were not atomic with respect updating the
> file  offset,  with   the result that the blocks of data output by the two processes might (incorrectly) overlap.  This problem was fixed in Linux 3.14.

In other words, if this is just multiple threads within one process, then there's no problem, if your kernel > 3.14; this is independent from the actual file system.

Comment: Thanks for the quote.
I am trying to develop a WAL functionality for one of our project.
I still did not get the answer if splitting my WAL to multiple files would be a better idea?

Comment: hm, since the kernel guarantees atomicity, there's no *functional* upside to multiple files, but of course the kernel would let your program run into blocking behaviour if the virtual file system write bufs are exhausted on a single file; on the other hand, WAL with many files sounds not unproblematic from a consistency aspect. It depends on how you're planning to establish (and whether at all) when committing that WAL to "persistent" storage.

Comment: Generally, if the same file system might be read by other processes, the overhead of communicating changes to many files to other processes would be worse than the overhead of arbitrating the write access to one file in the writer process.

Comment: In my application, only 1 process would ever read the file and that too only at boot

Comment: In which case I wonder why you'd put too much thought into it – the writing within the single process *is* fully guaranteed to work.